# Can't Get Program to Run

Tags: python, list, debugging, dictionary

This is a snippet of a program for my introduction class, and it keeps crashing before it can open. It gives a syntax error in line 12, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
#defines the median
def median(data)
    data=sorted(data)
#this happens if there is an odd amount of numbers in the count
    if len(data)%2==1:
        return(data[int((count-1)/2)])
#this happens if there is an even amount of numbers in the count
    else:
        return(data(int[((count-1/2)+(count+1/2)/2]))
count=0
#Creates a dictionary loop that inputs all numbers in the list
for data
    numbers{count+=0}:
        else
        break
    for number in numbers:
        count=numbers[number]
```

Comment: Count +=0.... That does nothing. Try count+=1

Comment: Still gives a syntax error. The error is highlighting the blank space behind "data" in line 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
#defines the median
def median(data)
    data=sorted(data)
#this happens if there is an odd amount of numbers in the count
    if len(data)%2==1:
        return(data[int((count-1)/2)])
#this happens if there is an even amount of numbers in the count
    else:
        return(data(int[((count-1/2)+(count+1/2)/2]))
count=0
#Creates a dictionary loop that inputs all numbers in the list
for data # in what:
    numbers{count+=1}: #your problem was that you weren't updating count 0+0 = 0
        else
        break
    for number in numbers:
        count=numbers[number]
```

Comment: Your for statement is wrong.  for i in something: is the format.

Comment: Thank you! As soon as you had it typed out I went through an "aha" moment - think I got ahead of myself!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `for` loop is syntactically incorrect. Should be something along the lines of `for d in data:`

See also Python explanation of for loop:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop